# AngularJS: Model not updating when using directive OR model-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the current section of html that is used to check a users password,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="auditName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Current Password </label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Current Password" 
        name="currentPassword" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-model="currentPassword" 
        required="" 
        password-new 
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-4" ng-if="form.$pending.oldPassword">checking....</div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-4" ng-if="form.$error.oldPassword">Please create a NEW password</div>
</div>

{{currentPassword}}
```

My issue is that the currentPassword is not being updated, so nothing is being displayed on the screen. If I remove the model-options AND I remove the reference to the new-password directive it will display as you type - so both of these are for some reason stopping the model from updating the value.

The directive new-password looks like this, and is still in a basic format I found elsewhere until I get this working properly,

```
app.directive('passwordNew', function ($timeout, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, model) {
            model.$asyncValidators.oldPassword = function () {
                //here you should access the backend, to check if username exists
                //and return a promise
                var defer = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function () {
                    model.$setValidity('oldPassword', true);
                    defer.resolve;
                }, 1000);
                return defer.promise;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not the issue, but `$timeout` already returns a promise, so you can return it in your function instead of another promise.

Answer (score 0):

The `{{currentPassword}}` in your HTML is outside the scope of the directive. You need to link the two scopes. Checkout "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Put something like this on the directive

```
  scope: {
    currentPassword: '='
  },
```

**EXAMPLE**

This is how I solve a similar problem

```
app.directive('availableEmail', [
  'dataSvc', (data:otolane.direct.IDataService) => {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('availableEmail', true);
          //only check the db if value is an email
          if (viewValue.length > 3 && !ctrl.$error.email) {
            data.account.checkEmail(viewValue)
              .then(() => {
                // data method resolves if email is available
                ctrl.$setValidity('availableEmail', true);
              })
              .catch(() => {
                //returns error if email is in use
                ctrl.$setValidity('availableEmail', false);
              });
          }
          return viewValue;
        });

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this but still can't seem to access it in my link: part, so I must be doing something wrong. With what you suggested should I not be able to set something to scope.currentPassword?